# style.right and .style.top options not updated in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two pictures, one of a wheel and another of an arrow. I want to position the arrow so it will point down on the wheel.

In my body part I defined:

```
<body onload="g1()">
    <img src="arrow.png" id="arrow" width=8%>
    <br>
    <center>
    <img src="wheel.png" id="wheel">
    <br>
    <h2 style="width:200px;" id="status"></h2>
    </center>
</body>
```

And my function here is:

```
        function g1()
        {
            var left1=screen.width/2;
            var tikli=document.getElementById("arrow");
            //tikli.style.right=0;
            //tikli.style.top=0;
            tikli.style.right=left1;
            tikli.style.top=left1;
            tikli.style.zIndex+=2;
            //rotateAnimation("wheel",8,710);
        }
```

Now the problem is, while the values of .style.right and .style.top are being updated, the arrow's position isn't. (I found out they are updated by inserting alerts in between).

Am I missing something in here? For the record, I tried it both in Chrome and in IE, and the arrow still doesn't move.

(ps. uploaded the pics to [here](http://pho.to/79FpP) )

Edit:
Attaching CSS script:

```
<style type="text/css">
        body{
            //font-size:22px;
        }
        #arrow{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:100px;
            right:500px;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Are they positioned, as in `position: absolute|relative|the other one`

Comment: @Musa absolute, attached the css now.

Answer (score 0):

`screen.width/2;` is going to give you a number, not a CSS length. You need to add `"px"` to it.

Comment: Done, but still doesnt change anything...
var left1=screen.width/2+"px";

Comment: Have you defined `screen`?

Comment: The weird thing is that it seems to be getting the screen's width as it should, sets the arrow's right pos as should, but doesn't actually move it.